# Calculate stock returns from long format data frame

Tags: r, finance

What would be best practice for taking a long format data frame of stock prices (containing multiple stocks) and producing a new data frame with summarized return statistics for each stock? I’m thinking of some solution with dplyr, group_by, and summarize. My input data frame has columns: Date, Ticker, and Price. I’d like the output to have a column for Ticker then multiple columns for each return statistic. I want return statistics to be customizable, so I can have “1 month return”, “year to date”, and even things like “return between March 3, 2019 and Feb 14, 2020”.

Here's an example of what my input looks like:

```
library(lubridate)
set.seed(100)
d_start <- as.Date("2019-01-01")
input <- data.frame(
  Date = rep(seq(d_start, today(), by = "1 day"), 3),
  Ticker = c(rep("AAPL", today() - d_start + 1), 
             rep("MSFT", today() - d_start + 1),
             rep("NFLX", today() - d_start + 1)),
  Price = c(runif(today() - d_start + 1, min = 20, max = 40),
            runif(today() - d_start + 1, min = 50, max = 90),
            runif(today() - d_start + 1, min = 150, max = 400))
)
```

And here's what I'd expect the output to look like.  With:
r1 as the return over the past 1 month,
r2 as the return from year to date, and
r3 as the return from Mar 3, 2019 to Feb 14, 2020

```
Ticker         r1         r2          r3
1   AAPL  0.1788484  0.1370241  0.24244384
2   MSFT -0.1466788 -0.2850910 -0.06895183
3   NFLX -0.4755626 -0.4964146 -0.06005490
```

Comment: please include a reproducible example including a sample of your dataset and an expected outcome. Also include any code you have already tried

Answer (score 1):

You're specifically looking for tidyquant package. More specifically tq_mutate().

A sample code would be as follows:

```
Stocks <- c("AAPL","MSFT","NFLX") %>%
              tq_get() %>%
              group_by(symbol)%>%
              tq_mutate(
                                  select = 'adjusted',
                                  mutate_fun = periodReturn,
                                  period = 'monthly',
                                  col_rename = 'return')
```

String vector should contain yahoo finance symbols. When importing multiple symbols tq_get() returns by default a long df and has additional arguments 'from' and 'to' to select dates of interest. If you already have your own information tq_mutate() works like an usual dplyr function.

Any doubt, this package is really well documented.

Comment: Thanks for this, but 2 things: 1) I cant seem to get that to work and 2) I still don't see how I could get the "custom date return" (r3 in my example) with this.  When I run the code I get "Error in merge_two_tibbles(tib1 = data, tib2 = ret, mutate_fun) : 
  Could not join. Incompatible structures."

Comment: The previous edit makes the code work, sorry. For each summary in you question you need to run a different set of tidyquant commands. For r3 in your question I would run a tq_mutate() with period.apply() after calculating the returns.